# How do i fix "unassigned variable instance_create referenced" in Gamermaker newest version

Tags: windows, game-maker

So I am getting an error message that says "unassigned variable instance_create referenced"
I am not sure why I get it but I have tried to fix it but with no luck, does anyone know what can cause this?

Here is my code, it is meant to be a point and click movement system.

```
// Initialize destination coordinates if they don't exist
if (is_undefined(_destinationX) || is_undefined(_destinationY)) {
_destinationX = instance_create(0, 0, obj_null);
show_message("Instance created for _destinationX");
_destinationY = instance_create(0, 0, obj_null);
show_message("Instance created for _destinationY");

}

// Set the coordinates for _destinationX and _destinationY objects
if ((!_destinationX.x && _destinationX.x != 0) || (!_destinationY.y && _destinationY.y != 0)) {
    _destinationX.x = x + 64; // set x coordinate
    _destinationX.y = y; // set y coordinate
    _destinationY.x = x; // set x coordinate
    _destinationY.y = y + 64; // set y coordinate
}

// Move towards the destination
move_towards_point(_destinationX.x, _destinationY.y, _speed);
```

I have tried a bunch of different things, I searched a bit and got the answer that i was missing an extention but i could never find it and i think it is for an older version of gamemaker.

Answer (score 1):

`instance_create()` as a build-in function does not exist. If you want to add an instance, you'll also need to specify the depth or layer.

So use `instance_create_layer()` or `instance_create_depth()` instead (and specify the layer or depth as parameter)

Example in the manual: https://manual.yoyogames.com/GameMaker_Language/GML_Reference/Asset_Management/Instances/instance_create_layer.htm

Comment: Of course, instance_create did used to exist, but hasn't for some time.  Also worth noting that if this is an old project with lots of instances of "instance_create", you could create your own script called "instance_create" that creates the instance in a default layer or at a default depth.